# Google maps get directions auto-fill to location via HTTP?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a simple way to auto fill the "to" field for google maps via URL/HTTP?  I already have lat,lng info.  I want to leave the from field blank or use the users default.

Can I append keys to a URL maps.google.com/directions?to=lat|lng?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can auto-fill it with an address:
http://maps.google.com/maps?&q=to:+1+Yonge+St+Toronto+ON

Or a lat/long pair:
http://maps.google.com/maps?&q=to:43.641965,-79.374649